# Sampling an arbitrary point within a DFT?

Tags: c#, fft

What I'm trying to do: I want to compress a 2D grey-scale map (2D array of float values between 0 and 1) into a DFT. I then want to be able to sample the value of points in continuous coordinates (i.e. arbitrary points in between the data points in the original 2D map).

What I've tried: So far I've looked at Exocortex and some similar libraries, but they seem to be missing functions for sampling a single point or performing lossy compression. Though the math is a bit above my level, I might be able to derive methods do do these things. Ideally someone can point me to a C# library that already has this functionality. I'm also concerned that libraries that use the row-column FFT algorithm don't produce sinusoid functions that can be easily sampled this way since they unwind the 2D array into a 1D array.

More detail on what I'm trying to do: The intended application for all this is an experiment in efficiently pre-computing, storing, and querying line of sight information. This is similar to the the way spherical harmonic light probes are used to approximate lighting on dynamic objects. A grid of visibility probes store compressed visibility data using a small number of float values each. From this grid, an observer position can calculate an interpolated probe, then use that probe to sample the estimated visibility of nearby positions. The results don't have to be perfectly accurate, this is intended as first pass that can cheaply identify objects that are almost certainly visible or obscured, and then maybe perform more expensive ray-casting on the few on-the-fence objects.

Comment: The best way is to use Matlab library.  You can create a dll in Matlab and then call from c#.

Comment: I don’t think you can (1) compress data using the DFT, or (2) cheaply obtain a single spatial sample from a 2D DFT, since each spatial point depends on all values in the DFT.

Comment: @CrisLuengo My understanding of FTs was that you can compress them by dropping the highest frequency waves, thus trading accuracy to reduce space in memory. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the form in which an FFT is storing the data.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but you don't need the frequency domain for that. Dropping the highest frequency components is equivalent to low-pass filtering, which smooths the signal. After smoothing you can resample with fewer samples, and then use interpolation to retrieve the value of the smoothed signal at arbitrary locations.